# How to override node attribute value within ruby block / using a value of variable in ruby block?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops, aws-opsworks

I am using Chef of AWS OpsWorks. I have a custom attribute JSON like below;

```
{
    "custom_attributes": {
        "custom_attribute_1": "default_value"
    }
}
```

and, I can use `#{node[:custom_attributes][:custom_attribute_1]}"` to print / use that value anywhere in my recipes. Then, I want to change that value and I can achieve it by mentioning it in `default.rb` file inside `attributes` directory of my cookbook, like below;

```
override['custom_attributes']['custom_attribute_1'] = "overridden_value"
```

Now, if I print / use this attribute, new value will get reflected. This works well.

Lets consider I haven't overridden the value and trying to use a ruby block for this like below;

```
ruby_block 'test_block' do
    block do
        node.override['custom_attributes']['custom_attribute_1'] = "overridden_value"
    end
    action :run
end

log 'message' do
    message "attribute value = #{node[:custom_attributes][:custom_attribute_1]}"
    level :info
end
```

Now, if we take a look at log, it will show `default_value` instead of `overridden_value`. If my understanding is clear, its happening because of `compile` and `convergence` phases. Can somebody show me how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

As per my research, I understand that the attribute assignment is happening at compile phase and ruby block evaluation is happening at converge phase. In that case, can somebody show me how to override / create new attribute using Chef Lazy? Below is a blog I came across;

https://blog.alanthatcher.io/lazy-is-good/

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd like to set a node attribute from within a `ruby_block`? It looks more like a scope (of variable) issue than compile/converge phases.

Comment: @seshadri_c I got your point. But the thing is, suppose I have an attribute value used across different recipies, and if the value is dynamic. So, even if I am not overriding the value and suppose if I am creating a fresh attribute using ruby block and mention it in my recipe, it will look blank. I agree with compile/converge phases and I understand thats what is happening.

Comment: The value you assign to a variable (or attribute) within `ruby_block` will be applied only within it. If you write a simple Ruby code to write the value of the attribute to a file in the `ruby_block`, you will see `overridden_value`.

Answer (score 1):

> can somebody show me how to override / create new attribute using Chef Lazy?

you can use [lazy evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#lazy-evaluation)

> In some cases, the value for a property cannot be known until the execution phase of a Chef Infra Client run. In this situation, using lazy evaluation of property values can be helpful. Instead of a property being assigned a value, it may instead be assigned a code block. The syntax for using lazy evaluation is as follows:
>
> `property_name lazy { code_block }`
>
> where lazy is used to tell Chef Infra Client to evaluate the contents of the code block later on in the resource evaluation process (instead of immediately) and { code_block } is arbitrary Ruby code that provides the value.

so you might want to use `lazy` as follows

```rb
log 'message' do
    message lazy { "attribute value = #{node[:custom_attributes][:custom_attribute_1]}" }
    level :info
end
```